# How do I update select variables in another file in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I apologize in advance if the solution to my problem is very straightforward and obvious, as I'm very new to shell scripting. For a program I'm working on, I need to update the contents of another file that was previously created. For example, say this is one of the files to be updated, student_1.item:

```
student_1 Sally Johnson 
3 9
Mr. Ortiz
```

I am to create another bash file that asks for the name of the file to be updated, and then prompts the user for the following one at a time:

```
Student Name:
Student Number:
Grade:
Age:
Teacher:
```

The user is able to leave any of the above blank, and whatever isn't filled in isn't changed in the original student_1.item file. Whatever is filled out, however, should be changed and updated to whatever the user put in.

I believe that I'd need to understand the concept of environment variables, but I'm a little stuck. Would I first need to read the lines into variables from student_1.item and then export any changed variables back into student_1.item?

Again, my apologies if this is a silly question. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit complicated, but here is untested solution: it reads a file line by line and assigns these lines to 3 variables. After that, these variables are parsed to get proper values of student.

```
# line number
n=0

# read file line by line
while read line; do
# assign line to a variable
case $n:
  0) firstline=$line
  ;;
  1) secondline=$line
  ;;
  2) thirdline=$line
  ;;
esac
# increment line number
n=$((n+1))
done < student_1.item

# parse each line variable
student_number=$(echo $firstline | cut -d' ' -f1)
student_name=$(echo $firstline | cut -d' ' -f2,3)
student_grade=$(echo $secondline | cut -d' ' -f1)
student_age=$(echo $secondline | cut -d' ' -f2)
student_teacher=$thirdline
```